# Laravel: access to variables inside facades

Tags: php, laravel

The code below is the method for sending the feedback message by Laravel. I want to create the variables which values are html fields names. However, the `$email_fieldName` is not accessibleinside the `Mail::send ...`/

```
public function sendFeedback(Request $request) {

    $email_fieldName = 'email';
    // ...

    if ($request ->isMethod('post')) {

        // ...

        $inputedData = $request->all();

        // $email_fieldName is accessible here

        $result = Mail::send('email', ['inputedData' => $inputedData], function($message) use ($inputedData) {

            // $email_fieldName is not accessible here
            $message->from($inputedData[$email_fieldName], $inputedData[$name_fieldName]);

            // ...

        });       
    }
}
```

I tried below simulation fiddle and it works. What wrong with the variable access in the code above?

```
$nameKey = "name";
$testBool = true;

if ($testBool) {
    $array= array("name"=>"Alex", "age"=>22, "student" => true);
    echo($array[$nameKey]);    
}
```

Comment: Do you know what closures are?

Comment: The class for anonymous function, I suppose.

Comment: Closure = anonymous function. When you want to use variables from different scope in anonymous function, you must specify them using `use` keyword. You did so with `$inputedData` but not with the rest of variables you're using

Comment: Moral of the story is that if you just grab code from here and there be sure you understand what each part does. You've already implemented the answer to your question in your code in a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mail function can't find the  $email_fieldName as you haven't mention it inside use()

Change

```
$result = Mail::send('email', ['inputedData' => $inputedData], function($message) use ($inputedData) {
```

with.

```
$result = Mail::send('email', ['inputedData' => $inputedData], function($message) use ($inputedData, $email_fieldName) {
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Very appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are in the anonymous callback of the Mail::send method. `$email_fielName` is not in that scope.

The same way you have `use ($inputedData)`, you should should add `$email_fieldName` :

```
Mail::send('email', ['inputedData' => $inputedData], function($message) use ($inputedData, $email_fieldName) {
```

(And probably `$name_fieldName` too given your code)

Comment: Thank you for the answer with explanation!